# Arranging buttons side by side

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-sprites

please help me arrange these 3 buttons horizontally like this photoshopped image:

[image: made with photoshop]

Please take a look at the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FzYkJ/1/).

CSS:

```
a.facebookbt {
    background: url(http://i1068.photobucket.com/albums/u445/neobx/bonus5.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 132px;
    height: 52px;
    display: block;
}
a.facebookbt:hover { background-position: 0 -52px; }
a.facebookbt:active { background-position: 0 -104px; }

a.twitterbt {
    background: url(http://i1068.photobucket.com/albums/u445/neobx/bonus5.png) no-repeat -132px 0;
    width: 132px;
    height: 52px;
    display: block;
}
a.twitterbt:hover { background-position: -132px -52px; }
a.twitterbt:active { background-position: -132px -104px; }

a.abpbt {
    background: url(http://i1068.photobucket.com/albums/u445/neobx/bonus5.png) no-repeat -265px 0;
    width: 286px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
a.abpbt:hover { background-position: -265px -52px; }
a.abpbt:active { background-position: -265px -104px; }​
```

HTML:

```
<a class="facebookbt" href="javascript:;"></a>

<a class="twitterbt" href="javascript:;"></a>

<a class="abpbt" href="javascript:;"></a>​
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the image was made with photoshop.

Comment: I can tell you to apply "float : left;" to each of three button styles.  Or I can tell you to go read up on floating stuff in general, because (as this newbie CSS coder can say with certainty) it's an important concept.  And to get the spacing, use padding or margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a { float:right; margin-left: 5px;}
```

and change the html markup to this way:

```
<a class="abpbt" href="javascript:;"></a>
<a class="twitterbt" href="javascript:;"></a>
<a class="facebookbt" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

This way the layout will be *aligned to the right*, and *in the correct order* like in your screenshot.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/FzYkJ/12/

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
a {
    float:left;
}
​
```

or

```
a {
    display:inline-block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
float:left;
```

to each button

http://jsfiddle.net/FzYkJ/2/

Comment: @ShyamSundar Can we select this as the answer? (check)